# Linux kernel - printk to a file

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I was debugging my syscall and I found that dmesg prints so many lines which made me couldn't see all of my `printk`.

Is it possible to `printk` to a file?

Comment: indeed, that `dmesg | grep > out.txt` can be a solution since I can grep my specific keyword there and print to a file. However, it will be a problem when I only want printk for my current process, and it also prints all of the old process logs

Comment: `printk` prints to a ring buffer accessible via `/proc/kmsg`. If you lose messages, recompile kernel with larger buffer (`CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT`). If you see too many messages, learn filtering (i.e. `grep`). Also, consider other debugging techniques (SystemTap, ftrace).

Comment: Before starting to debug your `syscall` do `$ sudo dmesg -c` to clear the buffer so that it can store more messages from printk.

Comment: Set up syslog / sysklogd / rsyslogd / whatever. This reads `/proc/kmesg` and can be persuaded to parse it appropriately.

Comment: Start considering tracing framework, otherwise all comments here and your question are wrong.

Comment: ok, thanks! for now the best solution is to trace the system logs with dmesg -c or other system commands.. I will just leave this question intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `trace_printk()` instead of `printk()`

And your prints should be in ftrace buffers.

```
      $ cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      $ cat trace
```

Refer http://june-takeout.blogspot.dk/2010/01/debugging-kernel-using-ftrace-part-1.html and see section "Using trace_printk()"

Answer (score 0):

The major difference between *printk()* and *printf()* is the capability of the former to specify a loglevel. The kernel uses the loglevel to decide whether to print the message to the console. The kernel displays all messages with a loglevel below a specified value on the console.

**On a standard Linux system, messages from the log buffer go through syslogd to /var/log/messages.**

Otherwise you could check your syslogd configuration to see where they go.

If you don't have syslogd at all and have systemd it's possible you could find your messages with `journalctl -k -f`

Comment: There no such thing as "standard Linux system", so you should check `/var/log/syslog` on Debian derivatives ;)